# Prove: $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:\sin(x)+xy\leq 5\}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Prove: $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:\sin(x)+xy\leq 5\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

So the function is continuous as a sum and composition of continuous functions and the preimage is $f^{-1}(-\infty,5]$ so it not closed and not open?

Comment: hint : convergence

Answer (score 2):

Closed need not imply not open. Sets can be both open and closed, but writing
the set as $f^{-1}[(-\infty,5]]$ where $f(x,y)  =xy + \sin(x)$ shows it is *at least* closed, as the pre-image of a closed set ($(-\infty, 5]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$; what is its complement?) under a continuous function $f$.

And this is all that was asked.

Comment: But isn't half open half closed interval is neither open nor closed?

Comment: @gbox this holds for finite intervals like $(1,2]$ but the complement of $(-\infty, 5]$ equals $(5, \infty)$ which is open. All sets of the form $[a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty, b]$ are closed (there are no points $\pm \infty$ in the reals, and these sets are always closed in any ordered space by the definition of the order topology).

Answer (score 0):

if $x=0$ then any $y$ works ($(x,y)$ is in the set for $x=0$ and any $y$).

Therefore we can write
$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:sin(x)+xy\leq 5\}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x<0\land y\ge\frac{5-\sin x}{x}\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x=0\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x>0\land y\le\frac{5-\sin x}{x}\}$$ and since $f(x)=\frac{5-\sin x}{x}$ is a continuous function, there is a sum of 3 closed sets. A sum of finitely many closed sets is closed.

Comment: Seems like overkill. No need for this, I think.

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at 0